# NetBeans 7.4 Javascript CDNJS

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I'm new to NetBeans version 7.4, I have been search for a while how to add CDNJS libraries to NetBeans.  When I open the project properties, under JavaScript Files there are no libraries available.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Added the following to the /nbproject/build.xml and it worked

```
<target name="get-cdnjs-jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/extsrc"/>
    <get src="https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/archive/master.zip" dest="build/cdnjs-temp.zip"/>
    <javac srcdir="extsrc" destdir="build/extsrc"/>
    <java classname="RemoveContent" fork="yes">
        <arg file="build/cdnjs-temp.zip"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="build/extsrc"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
    <echo message="File build/cdnjs-temp.zip.empty was generated."/>
    <echo message="Rename it and upload it as external/cdnjs.zip"/>
</target>
```